# Facing Issue in Storm HDFS Bolt in Kerberos Enabled HDP 2.6 cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kerberos, hadoop-streaming

I have enabled Kerberos Security in my HDP 2.6 cluster, on which services- Kafka and Storm are installed prior to enabling Kerberos.

The topology that I am running has kafka-spout followed by hdfs-bolt. So, CSV data from a specific Kafka topic is ingested using in-built Kafka Spout, and then transferred to HDFS directory using in-built HDFS Bolt.

I am Facing an error:
**SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]**

**Code:**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("hdfs.keytab.file","/etc/security/keytabs/storm.headless.keytab");
    map.put("hdfs.kerberos.principal","storm-hdp26ks@VSS.COM");
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put("hdfs.config", map);
    conf.put(HdfsSecurityUtil.STORM_KEYTAB_FILE_KEY,"/etc/security/keytabs/storm.headless.keytab");
    conf.put(HdfsSecurityUtil.STORM_USER_NAME_KEY,"storm-hdp26ks@VSS.COM");
    conf.setNumWorkers(1);

    HdfsBolt hdfsbolt = new HdfsBolt()
            .withFsUrl(hdfsUrl)
            .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat).withRecordFormat(recordFormat)
            .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy).withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy).withConfigKey("hdfs.config");

StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
```

**Error:**

```
Thread-7-hdfs-bolt-executor[3 3] [ERROR]
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: 
SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

Please let me know if I need to do any other steps/config related changes for storm-hdfs connector to work with Kerberos.

Comment: Quick fix: make sure that Storm CLASSPATH contains directory `/etc/hadoop/conf/` or whatever directory contains **up-to-date** Hadoop conf files stating that the HDFS clients must use Kerberos auth when initiating the connection. Because all Hadoop libraries will scan the CLASSPATH for directories, and look for their config files in these directories; if no file is found then they will revert *silently* to hard-coded defaults *(e.g. "simple" auth)* for any property not set explicitly in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SamsonScharfrichter
Please also can you let me know how can I add /etc/haddop/conf in storm CLASSPATH.

Comment: Well, I never used Storm, but a quick Google search suggests that you should _"set **storm-site topology.classpath** to etc/hadoop/conf"_  cf.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/METRON-465

Comment: Thanks a lot :) @SamsonScharfrichter ..

Comment: Hi @Niraj were you able to resolve ? facing the same issue. Tried all config options still getting SIMPLE auth error on kerberized cluster